# Причинение смерти?

Tags: выбор-слов

**Причинение смерти по неосторожности** — словосочетание, сотворённое в юридической среде, при всём уважении к ней и УК представляется нелепым. Прежняя форма (убийство по неосторожности или непреднамеренное) кажется приличней, хотя тоже спорна. Не лучше ли говорить о *лишении жизни*?

Comment: "Лишение" может восприниматься как временное ("лишение свободы"), или продолжительное (растянутое во времени).  "Причинение" не имеет разных толкований, это - акт.

Comment: Причинение боли может быть пожизненным.

Comment: Не думаю.  Боль - результат заболевания или травмы.  При этом актом будет причинение вреда или нанесение ущерба.

Comment: Щепка, попавшая в носок, долго, если не остановиться, будет причинять боль. Боль и от неразделённого чувства случается. Однако, не о лишении свободы речь, даже пожизненно. Лишение жизни не бывает ни временным, ни продолжительным. Здесь лишить означает отнять.

Comment: Не пойму я, при чём тут человеческие ощущения, неразделённые чувства и проч.  Законодательный документ - не беллетристика. Терминология его заранее установлена и имеет весьма ограниченное трактование.

Comment: Ограниченное, это вы в точку. За причинение жизни по неосторожности статьи нету.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что слово "**причинение**" в юридических сферах применяется вполне сознательно - для обозначения действия, **ставшего** (в строго юридическом смысле) **причиной** смерти человека (или ущерба, вреда). Это не обязательно единственная физическая причина, а просто какое-либо действие (или бездействие), за которое в конкретной ситуации признаваемый виновным нёс ответственность, напр. в силу должностного положения, обязанности принять меры безопасности в связи с каким-то своим занятием и т.п. - он мог и не подозревать о произошедшем по его вине. Вероятно, юристам требовалась формулировка связи **вины с причиной**, и отсюда такое далёкое от быта слово (*виновен тот, чьи действия стали причиной*).

Comment: Всё верно вроде бы, спасибо. Однако, слова уж больно далеки по масштабу. Причинять много страданий, неудобств, боли и горя — это понятно, так как всё это в прижизненных ощущениях человеческих.